# Rails -- Can't set value for date_select in form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, datetime, forms, date

I'm pulling data from an API where the date data comes in as "2008-02-11 00:00:00 "

I would like that data to go into my form within the date_select as a value so I can view it correctly before I add it into my database.

The view looks like

```
<%= f.label :start_date %><br />
<%= f.date_select :start_date, :value => " #{@stdate[idx]} " %>
```

The object is actually an array of dates since I'm doing this action several times do thats why the [idx] is there; serving as an index.

<%= @stdate[idx] %>  ends up outputting "2008-02-11 00:00:00 " but the fields for the date_select helper only outputs the current date "2010" "June" "5" in those dropdown date selects fields...

Do I need to set the values of the Year, Month, and Date Individually? I have Chronic and tried to parse the object before using it as a value for the date_select and that didnt work either.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 13):

You wouldn't use the `:value` option but the `:default` option and pass a DateTime object to it.

Answer (score 0):

There is no `:value` option for `date_select`. In your example, the value of the dropdowns will be obtained from the `start_date` attribute of whatever object you passed in when you started the form builder `f`.

On this object, you can simply set the `start_date` attribute before rendering, even if you're not actually saving it there.

There's also a `select_date` helper, which is the variant that is not linked to an object, and just allows you to pass a value. But that requires more manual labor, because it doesn't work out of the box with `update_attributes`.